# Setting sql_mode command when spinning up mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, ubuntu, global

I need to set this global config value in mysql to allow zeros in Date fields, to be automatically set as part of the docker images setup and configuration.

SET GLOBAL sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,NO_ZERO_DATE';

No method I have tried works successfully.

My environment:

- ubuntu vps, laravel project
- docker containers (mysql is run as a dependency when I "docker-compose up -d --build nginx" along with redis, etc.)

I tried creating a file "sql_mode.cnf" that contains

SET GLOBAL sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,NO_ZERO_DATE';

and called the file from mysql.prod.dockerfile via docker-compose.prod.yml as follows but it's not working. Possibly some error issues with file access?

Is this even the right method? Is there a better one?

docker-compose.prod.yml (extract):

```
  mysql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: mysql.prod.dockerfile
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_USER: datauser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pwd
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
    networks:
      - laravel
```

mysql.prod.dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:8.0.32

COPY sql_mode.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/

RUN echo "SET GLOBAL sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,NO_ZERO_DATE';" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_sql_mode.sql
```

sql_mode.cnf:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,NO_ZERO_DATE';
```

This is the "docker logs mysql" output:

This is the log from running the docker. But the zeroes in date setting did not take. Why?

```
remote: #3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.32
remote: #3 DONE 0.0s
remote:
remote: #4 [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.32
remote: #4 CACHED
remote:
remote: #5 [internal] load build context
remote: #5 transferring context: 94B 0.5s done
remote: #5 DONE 0.6s
remote:
remote: #6 [2/3] COPY sql_mode.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/
remote: #6 DONE 0.1s
remote:
remote: #7 [3/3] RUN echo "SET GLOBAL sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,NO_ZERO_DATE';" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_sql_mode.sql
remote: #7 DONE 0.7s
remote:
remote: #8 exporting to image
remote: #8 exporting layers 0.1s done
```

---

Why didn't this work?  Is there a better way to do this? I have not found any guides online for how to set this up - are there any?

I would be so grateful for any help - I've worked on this for days :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```html
mysql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: mysql.prod.dockerfile
    command: mysqld --sql_mode="ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,NO_ZERO_DATE"
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_USER: datauser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pwd
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! When I add this code, or the following one, the mysql container fails to spin up, complaining that Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist, etc.

I have also tried this line in my docker-compose.yml, with the same failed outcome: MYSQL_INIT_CONNECT: "SET @@global.sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE'"

Comment: Usually, that's data corruption. I guess if you are only setting this up there is nothing important in that DB yet? Try docker-compose down -v --remove-orphans (it will remove both volumes and any dangling images) and then spin it up again. It will run the whole init from the start. If you are interesting what it does on init, here are the script https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/1bfa4724fe112b4246672ed2b3c42142f17d5636/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh

Comment: This fixed the error and I reran with your solution and... it worked! You are amazing - I am SO grateful. I must have corrupted something while trying all sorts of different ways to get the zeroes setting in place. Thanks!!